# Why Recyclerview item click is not working in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement recyclerview item click listener in my project. I have writen and tried codes with the adapter and fragment class. But it is not working. Here is my code

This is the adapter code

```
class OnBoardingAdapter(private val itemsParam: Array<String>, private val onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit) : Adapter<OnBoardingAdapter.OnBoardingViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OnBoardingViewHolder {
        val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_on_boarding, parent, false)
        return OnBoardingViewHolder(layout){
            onItemClick(it)
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return itemsParam.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OnBoardingViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = itemsParam[position]
        holder.setItem.text = item
        holder.setItemCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80F8D1"))
    }
    class OnBoardingViewHolder(itemView: View, onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val setItem: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName)
        val setItemCard: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCard)
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClicked(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here this is my Fragment code

```
class StatesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var statesRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_states, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)



        statesRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.statesRecyclerView)


        val statesArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.statesArray)
        val adapter = OnBoardingAdapter(statesArray){
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        statesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        statesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the item click on recyclerview so i can perform different actions on different items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add interface in adapter like below and after that you have to set adapter.

Adapter

```
class OnBoardingAdapter(
    private val itemsParam: Array<String>,
    private val itemView: ItemClick
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OnBoardingAdapter.OnBoardingViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OnBoardingViewHolder {
        val layout =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_on_boarding, parent, false)
        return OnBoardingViewHolder(layout);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemsParam.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OnBoardingViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = itemsParam[position]
        holder.setItem.text = item
        holder.setItemCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80F8D1"))
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemView.itemClick(position)
        }
    }

    class OnBoardingViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val setItem: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName)
        val setItemCard: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCard)
    }

    interface ItemClick {
        fun itemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

set adapter like this

```
var adapter = OnBoardingAdapter(statesArray, object : OnBoardingAdapter.ItemClick{
        override fun itemClick(position: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to call lambda function, call it like this:

```
onItemClicked.invoke(adapterPosition)
```